# Change Array of multi integer vectors to single value for each vector in Numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array below, which I want to make each row randomly have a single 1 or all zeros, but only the current 1 values can be converted to 0.  I have a check below that was going to do this by seeing if there is a 1 in the row and if the summed value is greater or = to 0. I am hoping there is a simple approach to do this that is just escaping me at present.

```
A = np.array([
        [   0   ,   1   ,   1   ,   0   ,   1   ]   ,
        [   1   ,   0   ,   0   ,   1   ,   1   ]   ,
        [   0   ,   0   ,   1   ,   0   ,   0   ]   ,
        [   0   ,   1   ,   0   ,   0   ,   1   ]   ,
        [   1   ,   0   ,   0   ,   0   ,   0   ]   ,
        [   0   ,   0   ,   1   ,   1   ,   0   ]   ,
        [   0   ,   0   ,   0   ,   0   ,   0   ]   ,
        [   1   ,   0   ,   1   ,   0   ,   0   ]   ,
        [   1   ,   0   ,   1   ,   1   ,   1   ]   ,
        [   0   ,   0   ,   1   ,   1   ,   0   ]   ,
        [   0   ,   1   ,   0   ,   1   ,   0   ]   ,
        [   0   ,   1   ,   0   ,   0   ,   1   ]   ,
        [   0   ,   0   ,   1   ,   1   ,   0   ]   ,
        [   0   ,   1   ,   1   ,   0   ,   1   ]   ,
        [   0   ,   0   ,   1   ,   0   ,   0   ]   ])

if np.any(A[0] == 1)==True and np.sum(A[0])>=0:
    change row to all 0's randomly or keep one of the existing 1 values randomly.  Ideally, if it could do it to the whole array, it would be very useful, but row by row is fine.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can randomly select per row the column you want to keep:

```
m, n = A.shape
J = np.random.randint(n, size=m)
```

You can use these to create a new array:

```
I = np.arange(m)
B = np.zeros_like(A)
B[I,J] = A[I,J]
```

Or if you want to modify `A`, e.g. use bit shifting:

```
I = np.arange(m)
A[I,J] <<= 1
A >>= 1
```

Comment: Thank you for the direction, I am not sure I made this explicitly clear enough.  In each row, I want to randomly set the whole thing to 0, or only have a single 1, in the place where a current 1 is.  These are essentially availability shifts for a person, so a person is available for 3 shifts in row 1, but is limited to only work 1 of those 3 shits.  I am trying to generate individuals for a genetic algorithm based on this schedule preference limitation.